# Can std::vector<T>::iterator simply be T*?

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, iterator

Simple theoretical question: would a simple pointer be a valid iterator type for `std::vector`?

For other containers (e.g. list, map), that would not be possible, but for `std::vector` the held data is guaranteed to be contiguous, so I see no reason why not.

As far as I know, some implementations (e.g. Visual Studio) do some safe checks on debug build. But that is in UB territory, so for well defined behavior I think there is no difference.

Apart for some checks ("modifying" undefined behavior), are there any advantages of using a class instead of a simple pointer for vector iterators?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible.

Comment: At least it's guaranteed it behaves exactly the same way an iterator would.

Comment: any advantages of using a class instead? I guess there are as all major implementations use a class, but I fail to see any other advantages other than the checks I've mentioned.

Comment: iterators? yes. But how would you implement reverse iterators without a class?

Comment: @Dutow haven't thought about that. Good point.

Comment: @bolov Have you checked? I don’t know what current library implementations do (and I suspect you might be correct since compilers have gotten really good at optimising that stuff) but previous versions of major libraries *did* use `T*` for `std::vector<T>::iterator` in release mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> would a simple pointer be a valid iterator type for `std::vector`?

Yes. And also for `std::basic_string` and `std::array`.

> are there any advantages of using a class instead of a simple pointer for vector iterators?

It offers some additional type safety, so that logic errors like the following don't compile:

```
std::vector<int> v;
int i=0;
int* p = &i;
v.insert(p, 1); // oops, not an iterator!
delete v.begin();  // oops!

std::string s;
std::vector<char> v;
// compiles if string and vector both use pointers for iterators:
v.insert(s.begin(), '?');
std::array<char, 2> a;
// compiles if array and vector both use pointers for iterators:
v.erase(a.begin());
```

Comment: I completely read the wrong line in the standard, so `std::array` iterators are actually *implementation defined* (sorry... ), but I can't think of any sane implementation that would use something else.

Comment: @Holt an implementation could want to use a class to enable extra safety checks in a debugging mode, so that `std::array<int, 2> a, b; std::for_each(a.begin, b.end(), f);` can be diagnosed at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be `T*`, but that has the slightly annoying property that the ADL-associated namespace  of `std::vector<int>::iterator` is *not* `std::` ! So `swap(iter1, iter2)` may fail to find `std::swap`.

Comment: Great point, but bad example because the standard idiom is to call `swap` after a `using std::swap;` using declaration. There are plenty of other examples though, e.g. `sort(v.begin(), v.end());`

Answer (score 0):

A food for thought - an iterator class can also be implemented by the terms of *indexes* instead of *pointers*

of course, when a vector reallocates, all the pointers , references and iterators become invalidated.

but at least for iterators, that doesn't have to be the case always, if the iterator holds an index + pointer to the vector, you can create non-reallocation-invalidated iterators that simply returns `(*m_vector)[m_index]`. the iterator is invalid when the vector dies out, or the index is invalid. in other words, the iterator is invalid only if the term `vec[i]` is invalid, regardless of reallocations.

this is a strictly non standard implementation of a vector iterator, but non the less an advantage to class based iterator rather than raw pointer.

also, UB doesn't state what should happen when an invalid iterator is being dereferenced. throwing an exception or logging an error fall under UB.
that means that an iterator which does bound checking is significantly slower, but for some cases where speed is not important, "safe but slow iterator" may have more advantages than "unsafe but fast iterator"

Comment: An implementation that encourage to use UB (use iterators that the standards says are invalid)... I would stay away from that. Issuing diagnostic errors when UB that's another story, but by design "making" UB "work" would be a very bad decision in my opinion.

Comment: it's not making UB "work", I'm talking about alternative approach to iterators which does not impose UB on reallocation. this is not backed up by the standard. this is a simply a claim that iterator does not have to be a wrapped pointer, and by thinking so we can have different advantages than a pointer based iterator.

Comment: @David Haim it probably would be interesting to measure the performance implications that this change has. I expect it to be much slower, then an usual pointer iterator

Comment: @Vincent, I actually did it a while ago. with VC++14 on Windows 7 the index based iterator was about 150% slower than raw pointer.

Comment: @DavidHaim this makes it barely usable in the most use cases. But it would be nice to have a vector_view which doesn't get invalid by resizing and which can get used to get the actual iterators, which are raw pointer. I have to give the range proposal a look, maybe there is something like this.